# how to make a scroll-bar of a y-scrollable DIV appears on the right instead of left

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have a div with this style:

```
  height:150px; overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:clip;
```

In my `<body>` style I have direction right to left.

In Chrome/Safari the scroll-bar appears on the right side and that's what I want. How can I make that happens in IE/FF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because I have the body direction `rtl` I get that scroll bar to the left in IE & FF. the solution is the give `direction:ltr;` to the containing element of that scrollable `DIV`.

Answer (score 0):

There are some other answers on this website but you can use jQuery Scrollpane to position your scroll bar

[Scrollpane page](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html)